# Did you nominate MVPs for 2017?

Tags: discussion

Happy festive holiday period / Merry Christmas / Happy Kwanza / Whatever suits you.

As usual at this time of the year, the SDL Web MVP Selection panel is searching for those among you that share your passion, knowledge and know-how with exceptional contributions to the SDL Tridion community, be it through  SDL Tridion social network sites , by posting  community eXtensions or through your personal weblogs.

So... Have you [nominated your MVP candidates](https://community.sdl.com/solutions/content-management/tridion/tridion-developer/w/wiki/479.mvp-award-program) yet?

Answer (score 2):

Quick update - not really an answer, as this question is rather rhetorical...

We have received 33 nominations this year.

Selection is in progress.

Expect results before end of January. Good luck all.